# Why does this private template function compile? -> Compiler Bug VS 2009

Tags: c++, templates, compiler-bug

This compiles with out problems in VS 2009? Am I stupid?
GCC gives a warning, that the template is private....?
What am I missing?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class A
{
private:
    template<typename T>
    A& operator<<(const T & v)
    {
        cout << v << endl;
        return *this;
    }
};

int main()
{
   A a;
   a << 4;
   system("pause");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code should not compile - this is a bug (or silly extension) in VS. GCC should refuse it as well. The operator is inaccessible in the scope it is used.

Comeau treats this correctly:

```
"ComeauTest.c", line 28: error: function "A::operator<<(const T &) [with T=int]"
          (declared at line 14) is inaccessible
     a << 4;
```

EDIT: A relevant standard snippet, from 13.3/1

> [Note: the function selected by
>   overload resolution is not guaranteed
>   to be appropriate for the context.
>   Other restrictions, such as the
>   accessibility of the function, can
>   make its use in the calling context
>   ill-formed. ]

Answer (score 3):

Microsoft acknowledges the bug and claims it will be fixed in the next major release for the compiler (which I read as VC11/VS-whatever-is-after-2010 - probably not a service pack for VC10/VS2010):

- http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/649496/visual-c-doesnt-respect-the-access-modifier-for-operator-member-function-templates

from the comments, the fix appears to be already made to an internal compiler build.

Answer (score 0):

No, you're not stupid - it's broken code and should be rejected. The Comeau compiler (http://www.comeaucomputing.com/tryitout) does correctly reject it.